# What carburetor bench tests are common?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, carburetor, katana

So, August of 2016 I suddenly had gas flooding down the side of the engine on my Katana 600.  I pulled and rebuilt the carbs (they were super clean, but the seals and O-rings were all shot, plus a diaphragm was torn) over the Winter.  Put them back on the bike and rode for a couple weeks.  Ran great.

Then one morning cylinders 3 & 4 would not produce any power.  They share a common fuel rail and basically nothing else, so I pulled and cleaned the carbs *again*.  After that #3 came back to life.  #4 however, will only seem to operate at sizeable throttle openings.  So, sounds like a pilot circuit clog most likely.  I've had it on/off the bike several times now and everything seems *perfect* visually, but same problem on the bike.  Not only is it frustrating in general, but the bike is (IMO) pretty poorly designed and while the carbs are only annoying to remove, they are super difficult to reinstall (I'm getting good at it now, but I'm still cursing everyone even remotely related to '90's Suzuki engineering while I'm doing it).

What kinds of tests could I be running on the carbs on the bench that might catch issues *before* I go through the pain of reinstalling these things yet again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do any sort of bench testing would need a rig to mount the carbs and a method of driving the airflow : one person that did cover how to do this was David Vizzard for Minis. As I remember he was porting cylinder heads - he built it himself... Not for the faint-hearted.